# Increase bufferTime with a button. Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, flash-builder

I'm new with flash and I have a video recorder and a video player. I would like the user that receives the video to be able to delay the video using a +1 second button.

So what I tried to do is to create a button that increases the buffer of the video. Here is what I did.

I created a variable named 'buffer':

```
     private var buffer:int                  = 0;
```

then a function named 'bufferPlus' :

```
     private function bufferPlus():void{
            buffer = buffer + 1;        
        }
```

then:

```
      netStream.bufferTime  =   buffer;
```

and finally I have:

```
     <mx:Image left="400" bottom="20" id="plus" source="@Embed(source='Assets/plus.png')" click="bufferPlus()" buttonMode="true"/>
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea on what I could do in order to solve this ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `BufferTime` is the amount of buffering that is done before the video starts. If the video is already playing, increasing the bufferTime won't have any effect.

You could set it up so that the video pauses, but keeps buffering the incomming data and resume the video an second later.

Comment: Are you sure ? I finally did: private function bufferPlus():void{ netStream.bufferTime  =   buffer + 1;}, and it worked. But the problem is that it worked only once. I can delay the video by 1 second.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how I could Pause my video, make it buffering, and then resume it where it paused ? I really need help on that. Thank you !